# What is standard way of defining global closures in scheme?

Tags: macros, scheme, lisp, common-lisp, lisp-macros

So I want to know if there is standard way of having code like this:

```
(let ((x 10))
  (define (add10 a)
     (+ x a)))
```

I know about:

```
(define add10 (let ((x 10))
                 (lambda (a) (+ x a))))
```

but this will not work if I want to define multiple functions, I need to know standard way so I can write macro that will define functions. where you can call macro inside let:

```
(let ((x 10))
  (macro x))
```

and for instance macro will create list of functions:

```
(let ((x 10))
  (define (add1)
     (+ x 1))
  (define (add2)
     (+ x 2))
  (define (add3)
     (+ x 3)))
```

Is there standard way of defining functions add1..add3? In scheme I was testing, the functions will be local inside `let` and not accessible outside.

If you show macro code I'm only interested in lisp macros with `define-macro` and `quasiquote`, please no `define-syntax`, because this is mostly for use in my own lisp (based on scheme) where I have only lisp macros.

If scheme don't give support for something like that, does other dialect like Common Lisp allow something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(let ((x 10))
  (somemacro x))
```

->

```
(let ((x 10))
  (define (add1)
     (+ x 1))
  (define (add2)
     (+ x 2))
  (define (add3)
     (+ x 3)))
```

In Common Lisp:

```
CL-USER 43 > (defmacro somemacro (var)
               `(progn
                  (defun add1 () (+ ,var 1))
                  (defun add2 () (+ ,var 2))
                  (defun add3 () (+ ,var 3))))
SOMEMACRO

CL-USER 44 > (let ((x 10))
               (somemacro x))
ADD3

CL-USER 45 > (add1)
11

CL-USER 46 > (add3)
13
```

One sees that sometime. Generally exactly this is slight bad style in Common Lisp, because the file compiler will then not recognize that there are global function declarations, because inside the `LET` a `DEFUN` is not at *top-level*. If a function is defined in a file at *top-level*, then at compile time the file compiler would see that this is a function and may do special things like noting the signature in the compile-time environment, inlining it. etc.

Note that when `DEFINE` in Scheme defines a local function, one still *might* be able to do (depending on what the implementation does additionally to the standard):

```
(let ((x 10))
  ()
  (define (add1) (+ x 1)))
```

Note that in Common Lisp `defun` defines global functions and `flet` / `labels` define local functions.

Comment: The last paragraph in http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_eval_w.htm says that let over eval-when might be useful for defun/defmacro, while the description says that compile-time side-effects only take place when eval-when is a top-level form. Maybe there is a way to achieve what OP wants by wrapping the whole thing in eval-when (and I agree that this is bad style, btw)

Comment: will expanded function have `(+ x 1)` or `(+ 10 1)` what I need is `(+ x 1)`. I'm trying to simplify actual issue I'm having, where I have object that need to be in closure not evaluated and put into lisp code, since it can't have lips representation like number 10.

Comment: @jcubic: the expanded function has `x`.

Comment: That last example works in some Scheme and don't in other, I think it was working in previous guile or in Kawa (scheme in Java).

Comment: Can you explain what that empty list do in scheme? This seems to work in biwascheme but don't know why. where without empty list if don't work.

Comment: @jcubic: the empty list evaluates to the empty list. ;-)

Comment: but what the difference if you have it and don't. check https://www.biwascheme.org/ if you use it add1 is defined globaly and without it it's local. This is weird this works `(let ((x 10)) 1 (define (add2) (+ x 2)))`

Comment: That's weird maybe it's a bug in implementation, is this in the scheme spec?

Comment: That's in the Scheme spec. 'Definitions can occur at the beginning of a ⟨body⟩'. Now what might not be in the spec: what to do with non-top-level non-local DEFINEs inside a LET.

Comment: This don't work in guile, throw error that definition is in expression context where they are not allowed.

Comment: That's why I wrote 'might'. It could be an implementation specific thing. One als might check if an implementation has other ways to create a top-level variable.

Comment: `()` is not valid Scheme syntax and of course `define` needs to be in the beginning of a lambda body. The last code is therefore in violation of the Scheme reports and is undefined and unportable behaviour like mutating quoted lists in Scheme and CL. It might work, it might not, it might signal an error.

Comment: @Sylwester is doesn't, and it does. :) It doesn't work, and it does signal an error -- in Racket, both under `#lang r5rs` and `#lang racket` that I checked.

Answer (score 4):

In R7RS, the latest Scheme report, we have `define-values`. It can be used in this way:

```
(define-values (add1 add2 add3)
  (let ((x 10))
    (values (lambda () (+ x 1))
            (lambda () (+ x 2))
            (lambda () (+ x 3)))))
```

Of course for larger blocks one might want to make a local define and the reference it in `values` instead.

In the R7RS report you'll find a syntax rule for `define-values` that will work for R6RS and R5RS. It uses `call-with-values` where the values are passed to `list` and then `define` from that. I bet it also works inside `lambdas` sucn that the Scheme implementation actually can transform this into a `letrec` so while it is not very elegant it does the dirty work.

Comment: This is cool: I was trying to work out if `define-values` could be written as a macro, and it turns out that it can.  Thanks!

Comment: Can `define-values` be used inside let, or is it the same as with define, let and single lambda? If it's the same then there is use for it with case where let is outside of macro that generate functions.

Comment: @jcubic it works the same as `define`. if you do `(let () (define name ...))` then `name` becomes local probably transformed into a `letrec`. Thus you `let` needs to go in the expression as I have demonstrated. `define-values` is also useful when dealing with procedures that return several values eg. `(define-values (q r) (quotient-and-remainder 15 7))` and this is a use case fo local bindings.

Answer (score 3):

I think that no solution which wraps a binding around `define` can work at all portably or safely as the wrapped `define`'s will either construct local bindings (leading forms in the body) or be illegal (non-leading forms in the body), although I'd be happy for a Scheme-standards person to point out where I'm wrong.

Instead something like this slightly nasty hack ought to work I think.

```
(begin
  (define inc undefined)
  (define dec undefined)
  (let ((x 3))
    (set! inc (lambda (y)
                (set! x (+ x y))
                x))
    (set! dec (lambda (y)
                (set! x (- x y))
                x))))
```

Here I've relied on a constant called `undefined` which means 'not yet defined properly': Racket provides this in `racket/undefined` but it can in general be anything: you could just, somewhere, say

```
(define undefined 'undefined)
```

for instance.

The trick is to define the things you want at top-level with placeholder values, and then assign to them inside the `let`.

I'm sure a macro can be defined which expands to something like (this is why I have the whole thing inside a `begin`): I haven't done so because it's fiddly and I use Racket so I can't easily write old-style Lisp macros in it.

---

Note that the obvious approach in a modern scheme is to use `define-values`:

```
(define-values (x y) (let (...) (values ...)))
```

Does what you want.  As mentioned in another answer you can implement `define-values` as a macro if you only have multiple values.  But if you don't have multiple values at all, then you can use something which defines things based on a *list* of results:

```
(define-list (x y) (let (...) (list ...)))
```

Here are two rough variants of that macro: the first uses Racket's native macros:

```
(require racket/undefined)

(define-syntax define-list
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(define-list () expr)
     (let ((results expr))
       (unless (zero? (length results))
         (error "need an empty list"))
       (void))]
    [(define-list (name ...) expr)
     (begin
       (define name undefined)
       ...
       (let ([results expr])
         (unless (= (length results)
                    (length '(name ...)))
           (error "wrong number of values"))
         (set! name (begin0
                      (car results)
                      (set! results (cdr results))))
         ...))]))
```

while the second uses unhygenic macros in Racket:

```
(require compatibility/defmacro
         racket/undefined)

(define-macro (define-list names expr)
  `(begin
     ,@(let loop ([ntail names] [defs '()])
         (if (null? ntail)
             (reverse defs)
             (loop (cdr ntail)
                   (cons `(define ,(car ntail) undefined) defs))))
     (let ([results ,expr])
       (unless (= (length results)
                  (length ',names))
         (error "wrong number of values"))
       ,@(let loop ([ntail names] [i 0] [assignments '()])
           (if (null? ntail)
               (reverse assignments)
               (loop (cdr ntail) (+ i 1)
                     (cons `(set! ,(car ntail) (list-ref results ,i))
                           assignments)))))))
```

Note that neither of these has been tested, and I'd need to spend a little time convincing myself that the second is hygenic enough.

But with these:

```
> (define-list (inc dec)
    (let ([i 0])
      (list
       (lambda ()
         (set! i (+ i 1))
         i)
       (lambda ()
         (set! i (- i 1))
         i))))
> inc
#<procedure>
> (inc)
1
> (dec)
0
> (dec)
-1
>
```

Comment: Isn't it surprising that one can't define a global variable from inside a LET according to 'the' standard? Is that an unusual functionality?

Comment: @RainerJoswig Well, I hate the CL `(let (...) (defun ...) ...)` equivalent, so I'm biased.  If we're allowed Racket then `(define-values (...) (let (...) ... (values ...)))` works well, and I think `define-values` can be implemented as a macro, probably.